# How do you deploy a Ruby on Rails application on hostgator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do you deploy a Ruby on Rails application on hostgator?

Comment: do you succeed in deploying the application? I'm thinking of buying their service.

Answer (score 7):

Google is your friend. First hit for "hostgator rails".

http://forums.hostgator.com/ruby-rails-support-t13038.html?t=13038

Comment: Lol. The sad part is: whenever I google it this comes up as a top result. hah.